# Tabulator Invalid column definition option

Tags: tabulator

I have recently upgraded from Tabulator 4.9 to Tabulator 5.1.7.

Previously, I was adding some user-defined attributes into the column definitions.
The was done so that column headerContextMenu functions had ready access to info.
This all worked fine and we observed the expected warnings in the browser console.

With the new version, the presence of user-defined attributes in column definitions causes issues with headerContextMenu functions.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerContextMenu')**

The above error only occurs when there is a user-defined attribute in the column definition. I am seeing this on multiple tables in our application.

Are user-defined attributes in column definitions no longer allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Because Tabulator now uses optional module, not all column definition options always exist, it therefore warns you if it detects you are using an option that is not being watched by a module, just incase you have forgotten to install that module.

You can disable this functionality by setting the `debugInvalidOptions` option to `false`

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    debugInvalidOptions:false, 
});
```

Full details can be found in the [Debug Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/debug#options)

Comment: Hi Oli,
With the 4.9 version, I was adding non-native-Tabulator options to my columns. (that would cause invalid option messages) For version 5.1, the columns were no longer returning those attributes. Only the official-Tabulator column attributes were returned. Also, the debugInvalidOptions did not seem to be able to suppress the messages.

I have since moved this non-native information into a parallel data structure to avoid all of these issues. It would be nice if the columns had an "index" similar to those for rows so that accessing parallel info could be more direct.

Comment: The columns absolutely support custom definition options with the warnings disabled. if you are not seing these it might be a bug, but without knowing how you are trying to access them it is not possible to offer advice

Comment: you can retrieve columns by their field name using the getColumn function, im afraid i dont know what you mean by parallel info

Comment: "parallel info" ... I was referring to using the field name to look up information in a data structure separate from that of the table. Sorry for the poor nomenclature. I'll try a test case to show that col.getDefinition() was only returning official-Tabulator attributes and not the other attributes I was stuffing in.

Comment: I had the same warnings when have switched to the 5.4.4 ESM version. All I needed is to import full tabulator (or register additional modules) as described here: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/install#setup-basic

Answer (score 0):

An update to this issue, in version 5.4.2, the debugInvalidOptions wouldn't suppress the "Invalid column definition option" message when adding your own column properties, as per [GitHub Issue Here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/4057). They released a patch for this in version 5.4.4 that fixes this issue.